# 3D - Rotation Matrix from direction vector (Forward, Up, Right)

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, matrix, directx

I need to get rotation matrix from direction vector (vForward) I also have vRight and vUp vectors. All those vectors are unit vectors.

I just need to get rotation matrix.

To get rotation matrix for rotation in only one plane (xy) parallel to ground, I do this:
    XMMATRIX xmResult;

```
Vec3f vFwd = pPlayer->VForward;
vFwd.z = 0;
vFwd.Normalize();

xmResult = XMMatrixSet( vFwd.y,     -vFwd.x,    0,      0,
    vFwd.x,      vFwd.y,    0,      0,
    0,          0,          1,      0,
    0,          0,          0,      1);
```

Above code only get rotation matrix to rotate around Z axis:

I would like to get the code to rotate around all axis.
This is coordinate system I'm forced to use. I know it is strange:

[image: Coordinate System I'm using]

This is how I'm using my matrix later in code:

```
XMStoreFloat3((XMFLOAT3*)&vStart, XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3((XMFLOAT3*)&vStart), xmTransformation));
XMStoreFloat3((XMFLOAT3*)&vEnd, XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3((XMFLOAT3*)&vEnd), xmTransformation));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how you use your matrices, Right, Up and Forward should correspond to the rows or columns of your matrix.

```
xmResult = XMMatrixSet( vRight.x, vRight.y, vRight.z, 0, vFwd.x, vFwd.y, vFwd.z, 0, vUp.x, vUp.y, vUp.z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: I have no idea. This is all I get. I'm not good at math. I'm programmer and I need to calculate few positions.

Comment: This is how I will use that matrix to draw a line:  XMStoreFloat3((XMFLOAT3*)&vStart, XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3((XMFLOAT3*)&vStart), xmTransformation));
 XMStoreFloat3((XMFLOAT3*)&vEnd, XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3((XMFLOAT3*)&vEnd), xmTransformation));

Comment: How did you got to this? I want to learn something. I don't want to always ask.

Comment: @Hooch The answer to that would be too long to post in an SO answer. My suggestion is you pick up an introductory book on linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get one in book store in few days.

Comment: @Hooch Here's a link to the MIT introductory course: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/

Comment: There is one more problem. Rotation in xy is ok. But my line is rotated 90 degrees around vRight vector. So when player is looing at horizon line is pointing down. And when player is looking in sky line is pointing at horizon. This is last thing I want to fix before accepting your answer. I will get book later. But I need that to be done in 20 minutes. I'm little desperate now. All code is written. I just need to apply that matrix to whole drawing part.

Comment: Try swapping the order of the rows around.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13017/discussion-between-hooch-and-andreas-brinck)

Comment: Mine worked with **columns** r,u,f. +1 for giving me the solution to my rotation woes.